# form input in search array

Tags: php, arrays, forms

Write an application containing three parallel arrays that hold 10 elements each. The first array holds four-digit student ID numbers, the second holds first names, and the third holds the students grade point averages. Accept a student ID number and display the students first name and grade point average. If a match is not found, display an appropriate error message that contains the error ID number, and allow the user to search for a new ID number.

this is my unfinished code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$student = array (
$a = array ("F001"=>"a","F002"=>"b","F003"=>"c","F004"=>"d","F005"=>"e","F006"=>"f","F007"=>"g","F008"=>"h","F009"=>"i","F010"=>"j"),
array ("albert","berto","charlie","david","earl","francis","garry","harry","irish","james"),
array (1,2,3,3,2,1,2,1,3,1)
);

if (isset($_POST['search'])){
$idnumber = $_POST['search'];
if ($idnumber == $a){
    echo array_search("a",$student,true);}
else {
    echo "id number not found";}}

echo ('<form action="" method="POST">');
echo ('Id number: <input type="text" name="search">');
echo ('<input type="submit" value="search">');
echo ('</form>');
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: consider using MultipleIterator, and post to self

Comment: @Drew sorry im new in php. and dont now how to use multipleiterator. btw, thanks for the reply, :)

Comment: you can have separate arrays, or an array of arrays. same difference. after you search them, just do what the assignment said. If success, bingo, dump out 2 things. If failed, re-present the form

Comment: so If I understand, berto's ID is F002 and his grade 2 right ?

Comment: his GPA yeah, like 2, a C

Comment: What do the letters a,b,c,d,e,f stand for ?

Comment: I honestly think he was just screwing around with that stuff @LyesBEN

Comment: @LyesBEN yes. definitely thats the output. when the user inputs id number: F002.  output will be the name and the GPA. btw, thanks for the reply. :)

Comment: @LyesBEN and Drew yep right. i was trying to work on something on that. but failed.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own question. If you want it removed, flag it for moderator attention and request removal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Your mission, should you choose to accept it, is to write an application containing three parallel arrays containing 10 elements each.

- The first array holds four-character student IDs, the second holds first names, and the third holds the students grade point averages.
- The first element in the student ids array corresponds to the first element in the name array corresponds to the first element in the grades array and so on.
- The application should accept a student ID and display the student's first name and grade point average if found.
- If a match is not found, display an appropriate error message that contains the invalid ID number, and allow the user to search for a new ID number.

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
      <?php
          if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
              // move $students into the if statement cause we won't 
              // need it unless they're searching
              $students = array (
                  array ("F001"=>"a","F002"=>"b","F003"=>"c","F004"=>"d","F005"=>"e","F006"=>"f","F007"=>"g","F008"=>"h","F009"=>"i","F010"=>"j"),
                  array ("albert","berto","charlie","david","earl","francis","garry","harry","irish","james"),
                  array (1,2,3,3,2,1,2,1,3,1)
              );

              $idNumber = $_POST['search'];
              // we can use isset here because the student id *is* the key.
              // if it was the value, than we would use array_search() and
              // check if it returned false
              if (isset($students[0][$idNumber])) {
                  // array_keys returns the keys of an array as an array,
                  // allowing us to find the numerical index of the key
                  $studentIndex = array_search($idNumber,array_keys($students[0]));
                  // printf basically allows for formatted echoing. %s means
                  // a string. %d means a number. You then pass in your
                  printf('Student ID: %s<br>Name: %s<br>Grade: %d', $idNumber, $students[1][$studentIndex], $students[2][$studentIndex]);
              }
              else {
                  // use htmlspecialchars() to encode any html special characters cause never trust the user
                  printf('No student with ID "%s" found.', htmlspecialchars($idNumber));
              }
          }
      ?>
          <form action="" method="POST">
              Id number: <input type="text" name="search">
              <input type="submit" value="search">
          </form>
      </body>
  </html>
  ```

PHP docs for [array_search()](http://php.net/array_search),[array_keys()](http://php.net/array_keys),[sprintf()](http://php.net/sprintf)

Now assuming we don't need to have 3 parallel arrays, we can switch it to the following for less searching

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
            // note how the student id is now the key to that student's 
            // name and grade. This will allow us to access it more faster.
            $students = array (
                "F001" =>array("name"=>"albert"     ,"grade"=>1)
                ,"F002"=>array("name"=>"berto"      ,"grade"=>2)
                ,"F003"=>array("name"=>"charlie"    ,"grade"=>3)
                ,"F004"=>array("name"=>"david"      ,"grade"=>3)
                ,"F005"=>array("name"=>"earl"       ,"grade"=>2)
                ,"F006"=>array("name"=>"francis"    ,"grade"=>1)
                ,"F007"=>array("name"=>"garry"      ,"grade"=>2)
                ,"F008"=>array("name"=>"harry"      ,"grade"=>1)
                ,"F009"=>array("name"=>"irish"      ,"grade"=>3)
                ,"F010"=>array("name"=>"james"      ,"grade"=>1)
            );

            $idNumber = $_POST['search'];
            // since we set up our array the way we did, we know that: if
            // the key is found, there will be a name and grade associated
            if (isset($students[$idNumber])) {
                printf('Student ID: %s<br>Name: %s<br>Grade: %d', $idNumber, $students[$idNumber]['name'], $students[$idNumber]['grade']);
            }
            else {
                printf('No student with ID "%s" found.', htmlspecialchars($idNumber));
            }
        }
    ?>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            Id number: <input type="text" name="search">
            <input type="submit" value="search">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

*[it helps if you play this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAYhNHhxN0A)

Comment: lol. that last part. haha. thanks sir!

Comment: sir why array wont work if i change  this array "F001"=>"a","F002"=>"b","F003"=>"c","F004"=>"d","F005"=>"e","F006"=>"f","F007"=>"g","F008"=>"h","F009"=>"i","F010"=>"j" to not associative? like "F001","F002" ,"F003","F004"=,"F005","F006","F007","F008","F009","F010"

Comment: Because the if statement in the for loop is checking if the key ("F002") isset in the array. If you're switching the keys and the values, you have to use in_array instead of isset in the for loop and you're good

Comment: thanks sir! i understand now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a better structure for your students array.

```
<?php

$students = [
    ['F001', 'albert', 1],
    ['F002', 'berto', 2],
    ['F003', 'charlie', 3]
];

if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $id = $_POST['search'];
    $student = array_search($id, array_column($students, 0));

    if($student) {
        echo "student number $id with name " . $students[$student][1] .
             " has gpa " . $students[$student][2];
    }

    else {
        echo "student $id not found";
    }
}


echo ('<form action="" method="POST">');
echo ('Id number: <input type="text" name="search">');
echo ('<input type="submit" value="search">');
echo ('</form>');

?>
```

Refer to php.net documentation when you need information about functions parameters and return values.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but when i input F001 its says E_ERROR : type 1 -- Call to undefined function array_column() -- at line 16. line 16 is    $student = array_search($id, array_column($students, 0));

Comment: array_column is available since php 5.5.0, your php version might be outdated